# What do you call "<%= %>" and "<%# %>" in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been using them a lot but I'm not sure what you call them.

Also, is there a definition somewhere on what/how exactly they work? It's hard for me to search because I don't know what they're called.

Comment: [Embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: [Inline expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded code blocks.

There are several varieties of these:

```
<%= %> is the equivalent of `Response.Write()`
<% %> runs server-side code, like an if-else block
<%: %> is for HTML-encoding the data
<%# %> is for data-binding expressions
<%@ %> is for directives, usually page directives in ASP.NET
```